# Count number of clicks and display on another page [Windows Phone c#]

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am trying to count how many times button1 is clicked on page1, then display the amount of clicks on page2 in a textbox1.

I've tried to code below but it is giving me an exception error on the line '*String count= localSettings.Values["Count"].ToString();*'.

Is there another way to do what I want to?

**Page 1**

```
  private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        String count= localSettings.Values["Count"].ToString();
        int tc = int.Parse(count);
        tc++;
        localSettings.Values["Count"] = tc;

    }
```

**Page 2**

```
        var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        textbox1.Text = localSettings.Values["Count"].ToString();
```

Comment: I posted an answer and I was wondering if you used it. It did occur to me that using a helper class with a public static variable might be better since the local settings would probably be persistent (never reset until the app is uninstalled). So the helper class might be better. What did you end up doing?

Answer (score 2):

When you access "Count" for the first time, it does not exist. `localSettings.Values["Count"]` is therefore going to be null. You then try to call ToString() on an object that is null and that causes the exception.

Try this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var localSettings = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
    int tc = 0;
    if( localSettings.Values["Count"] != null )
    {
        String count= localSettings.Values["Count"].ToString();
        tc = int.Parse(count);
    }
    tc++;
    localSettings.Values["Count"] = tc;

}
```